# Detecting Cancel button in CommonDialog control

Tags: vb6

In VB6, if I press the `Cancel` button on an `Open File` dialog box, my filename is still added into my listbox.

For example:

```
Private Sub btnImportImage_Click()
    DailogOpenFile.ShowOpen
    If Trim$(txtEmailAttachment.Text) = "" Then
        txtEmailAttachment.Text = DailogOpenFile.FileName
    Else
        txtEmailAttachment.Text = txtEmailAttachment.Text & ";" & DailogOpenFile.FileName
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're using the `CommonDialog` control? If so, you need to set the `CancelError` property to `True` and then test for an error afterwards. For example:

```
Private Sub btnImportImage_Click()

    DailogOpenFile.CancelError = True

    On Error Resume Next
    DailogOpenFile.ShowOpen

    If Err.Number = &H7FF3 Then
        ' Cancel clicked
    Else

    End If

    ...

End Sub
```

Of course, you can also jump to an error handler:

```
Private Sub btnImportImage_Click()

    DailogOpenFile.CancelError = True

    On Error GoTo MyErrorHandler
    DailogOpenFile.ShowOpen

    ...

MyErrorHandler:
    ' Cancel was clicked or some other error occurred

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. @Bond  :D